# "IN" and "NOT IN" in CakePHP3

Tags: php, sql, scope, closures, cakephp-3.0

There is an example in the Cookbook:

```
$query = $cities->find()
   ->where(function ($exp, $q) {
      return $exp->notIn('country_id', ['AFG', 'USA', 'EST']);
});
```

In SQL this should be aequivalent to:
WHERE country_id NOT IN ('AFG', 'USA', 'EST')

Now, I'm trying to use a variable here. Sadly, this won't work:

```
$query = $cities->find()
   ->where(function ($exp, $q, $variable) {
      return $exp->notIn('country_id', $variable);
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `function ($exp, $q) use($variable)`

Comment: I've totally forgot about traits, thank you, sir

Comment: You mean variable inheritance, traits are something completely different ;)

Comment: But why is it not possible to pass the variable through normal function parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always find the easiest way to use IN and NOT IN is as follows in CakePHP

```
$query = $cities->find()
   ->where(['country_id IN' => $variable])
```

More information on auto generating in clauses is at the following link in the book. You can also use it to cast values to the type of the column automatically. To me it is more readable as well.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#automatically-creating-in-clauses

Comment: Thanks! That works even better!

Answer (score 0):

It works with "use", see: [PHP: Anonymous Functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$query = $cities->find()
   ->where(function ($exp, $q) use ($variable) {
      return $exp->notIn('country_id', $variable);
});
```